# Why for all $g\in \mathcal C_0[0,T]$, there is a unique $f\in \mathcal C_0[0,T]$ s.t. $f(t)-\int_0^t b(f(s))ds=g(t)$

Tags: real-analysis

We denote $$\mathcal C_0([0,T])=\{f:[0,T]\to \mathbb R\mid f\text{ continuous and }f(0)=0\}.$$

Suppose $b:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a Lispchitz continuous function. Set $$L(f)(t)=f(t)-\int_0^t b\big(f(s)\big)ds.$$
Why for all $g\in \mathcal C_0[0,T]$ there is a unique $f\in \mathcal C_0[0,T]$ s.t. $L(f)(t)=g(t)$ ?

For existence I really don't know. For unicity I tried as follow : Let $f$ and $h$ two solutions. Then 
$$|f(t)-h(t)|\leq \int_0^t |b(f(s))-b(g(s))|ds\leq K\int_0^t |f(s)-h(s)|ds,$$
so using Gronwall, we get $|f(t)-g(t)|\leq K\exp(t)$, but I can't really conclude that $f=g$. Any idea ?

Comment: Is there any given condition on $T$? If it can be chosen, try the contraction mapping theorem.

Comment: @cmk: No condition on $T$. I tried using contraction theorem, but I don't really see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the Banach fixed point theorem (also known as the contraction mapping theorem). The space $\mathcal C_0([0,T])$ is complete with respect to the supremum norm $$\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \lvert f(t) \rvert.$$ Fix $g \in \mathcal C_0([0,T])$ and consider the operator $A : \mathcal C_0([0,T]) \to \mathcal C_0([0,T])$ defined by $$(Af)(t) = g(t) + \int_0^t b(f(s))ds, \,\,\,\,\, f \in \mathcal C_0([0,T]).$$ Note that for $f,h \in \mathcal C_0([0,T])$, $$\lvert (Af)(t) - (Ah)(t) \rvert \le \int^t_0 \lvert b(f(s)) - b(h(s))\rvert ds \le KT\| f - h \|_\infty, \,\,\,\, \forall t \in [0,T].$$ Passing to the supremum shows that $\| Af - Ah\|_\infty \le KT \|f-h\|_\infty$. Now if $T < 1/K$, then $A$ is a contraction, and thus by the Banach fixed point theorem, you have a unique fixed point $Af = f$ which is the unique solution to the desired equation.

If $T \ge 1/K$, then you can't immediately conclude. However, in that case, you can "restart" the problem at $T_1 = 1/2K$. You have existence and uniqueness up to time $T_1$; you can step forward and establish existence and uniqueness up to $T_2 = T_1 + 1/2K$, then to $T_3 = T_2 + 1/2K$, etc. By taking enough steps you will get existence and uniqueness on the entire interval $[0,T]$.